# Subversion: recovery of version which took place before update

Tags: svn, tortoisesvn

I just started to use Subversion with TortoiseSVN.
Let's name my initial working copy as **A**.
I made in A a lot of changes and then commited it.

But when my colleague updated on my commit it did not compile at his machine.
Then he refused **A** and did a lot of changes and commits starting from version before **A**.
His last commit name is say **B**.

Then I updated my **A** to his **B**. 
Could you please help me with the following question:
How can I come back to my initial A version?

If I press in log "Update item to revision" or "Revert to this revision" or "Revert changes from this revision" it does not help.. I select revision A and then do this things and cannot see my work..

Comment: What do you exactly mean by "he refused A"? Did he revert it in SVN?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can update your working copy to A with the command:

`svn up -rA <path to your repository>`

where A is the revision number of your changes

or in TortoiseSVN, use TortoiseSVN → Update to Revision for your working copy.